# How can I get the distribution of event values in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

I'm tracking events on my websites and in those events I'm sending along an event value. The event value is how many times a person has done that particular event, so it could be a number from 1 to infinity.

I'd like to figure out where on a bell curve (or something like that) the event values are. I'd like to somehow find the distribution of the event values, but Google Analytics only gives me the average values.

How would you go about finding the distribution of event values in Google Analytics?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use metric-Filters in a segment to get the number of Events for each value.

[image]

If you use the API to extract the data you can write a loop to get every possible Value.

Still that is not the best solution. If you want to do this more than ones it would be better to add the value as Event-Label or Event-Action. GA saves this as a Dimension and you can easaly export and analyze this.

Comment: Sounds like the easiest solution. I'll try it out. Thanks.